# How to do drupal view execute diplay without forwarding

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-6

So I have the following code:

```
  $name = 'somename';
  $display_id = 'someid';

  if ($view = views_get_view($name)) {
    return $view->execute_display($display_id);
  }
```

If I do this, Drupal would redirect to the actual view page corresponding to the display id...

Is there a way so that instead of redirecting to the actual page, Drupal would instead return the HTML generated by the `$view->execute_display()` so that I can echo it rather than do a full redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id, $args);
```

$display_id is an optional argument.
$args is an optional argument, and if used, you just pass in an array with the values in order.

Comment: test it with a different ID or view to see if it redirects still.

Comment: I actually found out that the problem is with drupal calendar (I'm using it to try to render the calendar)...if I call the view that corresponds to a calendar whose display_plugin is set to 'calendar', it will do a complete redirection whereas if I use a view whose display_plugin is set to calendar_block or calendar_period, it'll just return the html just fine....do you have any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: Good find.  Sorry though, I don't have any suggestions besides using the block display.